# dynamic marking changing content JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I created a table that receives data from a SQL database to a PHP script that parse this back though my AJAX to the HTML page.

With this information I create the table.
It works and the beauty of it: every time the data changes the table changes.

BUT: it reloads the whole table with new data.

**What I want is to have it only reload the part that's been updates and then "mark" it until you mouse over it.**

Is there any function in JS that allows to compare 2 JSON encoded strings and then only update the part that's not similar?

I have use jQuery but haven't found anything as of yet.I apologies for not showing any code but it's protected from sharing

Comment: Is data only added or removed as well? Why don't you only return the new/updated data from the server instead of everything?

Comment: You can't share any of your code, but you expect us to share our ideas and knowledge to help your project along? Why doesn't this sit right with me... Oh, and BTW: comparing 2 JSON strings: parse them, and loop... just a thought

Answer (score 0):

You have to poll AJAX request to the server after every few seconds or minutes and see if there's any update. If so, you receive that update with say the id or index number of the data which you can replace with the new one. That way you won't have to update the entire thing.